# HTML CSS how do I underline every li in a nested list

Tags: html, css, nested-lists

Based on w3c the correct way in HTML for a nested list is.

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
    <li>Black tea</li>
    <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

However I want a border at the bottom of each item in the list, the following code underlines them all but Tea.

```
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `text-decoration: underline`?

Comment: Tea probably IS underlined but it's "covered up" by the line under GreenTea

Comment: wrap all the texts in span. and do underline the span instead. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/khS9K/).

Comment: li ul li { text-decoration:underline; } better to use class selectors to select the desired elements I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to solve it, I went with this.

```
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
}

li > ul > li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid purple;
}

li > ul > li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you mean border bottom on everything you will need to do something like this:

```
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
}

li > ul {
    border-top: 1px solid purple;
}

li > ul > li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yuq8v/2)
[Alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/yuq8v/)
[Same length lines](http://jsfiddle.net/yuq8v/1/) (but you'll have to find a way to indent the second level bullets)

Otherwise just use `text-dexoration`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use

```
text-decoration: underline
```

This applies to the text in the element.

Your problem is that the `li` containing `tea` actually does have a border, but it's a bottom border, so it is below the nested `li`.

Instead of using `text-decoration` you can also wrap the text in another element (`span` or `div`) inside the `li` elements, and apply the border to that. Such a solution using `div` is especially useful if you want the border to be the full width of the element instead of the text alone.

Answer (score 2):

The "Tea" `li` DOES have a border it's just 'masked' by the border of the last submenu `li`

See [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/a46CY/1/)

```
li {
    border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

li ul li {
    border-bottom:3px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone above mentioned that the border actually exists for text "Tea" which is at very bottom because `li` element has `display: list-item` assigned by default. You can make it visible by using `display: inline` but keep in mind that you will lose the features of `li` element such as `list-style-type` because they are only applicable for `display: list-item`.

```
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
    display: inline;
}
li:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UX3k7/)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the fact that the "Tea" li tag contains not just 'Tea', but every other ul and li tag pair except for the one containing "Milk".  The "Tea" li is getting underlined, which is actually appearing under the 'Green Tea' underline (if you look closely, you should notice a double underline there, especially if you add padding to you li tags.)   Your best bet in this situation (if you are building the list programmatically) is to wrap the li items in another tag:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Coffee</div></li>
  <li><span>Tea</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span>Black tea</span></li>
    <li><span>Green tea</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Milk<span></li>
</ul>
```

then change your code to:

```
li span{
    border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
}
```

This will ensure that the text gets underlined, and not the li tag containing the text.

Edit:=====================

This is the same thing that Mr Green is recommending in his comment

Answer (score 1):

Give it a class add add `display: inline-block` so:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
          <li class="underline">
             Some stuff here
          </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

and in your css:

```
.underline {
     display: inline-block;
     border-bottom: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
```